# How to use simulateKeyDownEvent to simulate typing a digit on a Flutter TextField?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

The code below contains a simplified Flutter TextField widget test. The purpose is to simulate typing a digit on the keyboard after having tapped on the TextField to put the cursor on it, Typing on backspace works, but trying to type on a digit or letter does not work. What is the solution ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: '100');

  testWidgets(
    'TestField simulateKeyDownEvent test',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: TextField(
                key: const Key('textField'),
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      Finder textFieldFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey("textField"));
      final TextField textField = tester.widget(textFieldFinder);

      expect(textField.controller!.text, '100'); // ok

      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await simulateKeyDownEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace);

      expect(textField.controller!.text, '10'); // ok

      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await simulateKeyDownEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.digit3);

      expect(textField.controller!.text, '103'); // not ok: 10 instead of 103
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use [enterText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/enterText.html) method instead of individual key presses? For example: `await tester.enterText(textFieldFinder, '103');`

Comment: Of course, this is the good way of entering text in the tested TextField. But I want to test that I can click on the TextField and then be able to type digits on it. Using enterText did not inform me that I had introduced a bug that made editing the TextField impossible.